# Can datetime handle AM string

Tags: python, numpy

Can we handle AM or PM in datetime string?

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
mytime = pd.to_datetime("1:30", format="%H:%M")
print mytime
```

will output like:

```
1900-01-01 01:30:00
```

But if we add a PM at the end as below, then error:

```
import pandas as pd
mytime = pd.to_datetime("1:30 AM", format="%H:%M")
print mytime
```

error output is:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  AM
```

Comment: Try `mytime = pd.to_datetime("1:30 AM", format="%I:%M %p")`. Note that strictly speaking, `%I` parses a zero-padded hour, so you may have to do some extra work, or you may find your OS's implementation of strptime accepts other conversion specifiers

Comment: Was there a particular reason you eschewed perusal of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the question is tagged as "python" and "numpy" I assume a NumPy solution is fine as well:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.strptime("1:30 AM", "%I:%M %p")
print datetime.strptime("1:30 PM", "%I:%M %p")
```

Output:

```
1900-01-01 01:30:00
1900-01-01 13:30:00
```